# foreach passing array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I'm trying to print using array matches strings...

The problem is... it prints only **BTC print**.

And if possible, also suggest a simply way to match using an *array parameter*.

```
Output Needed:

    BTC print
    ETH print
    DOGE print
    WAVES print
```

**Code**:

```
<?php
    $coins = array("BTC", "ETH", "DOGE", "WAVES");

    foreach ($coins as $coin) {

        $string = 'BTC';
        if (strpos($string, $coin) !== FALSE) {
            echo "BTC print";
            return true;
        }
        $string1 = 'ETH';
        if (strpos($string1, $coin) !== FALSE) {
            echo "ETH print";
            return true;
        }
        $string2 = 'DOGE';
        if (strpos($string2, $coin) !== FALSE) {
            echo "DOGE print";
            return true;
        }
        $string3 = 'WAVES';
        if (strpos($string3, $coin) !== FALSE) {
            echo "WAVES print";
            return true;
        }
    }
    echo "Not found!";
    return false;
```

Comment: remove the `return`s. It only loop once coz you returned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your printing line differs only in coin name you can use a simple loop:

```
$coins = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'DOGE', 'WAVES'];

foreach ($coins as $coin) {
    echo "$coin print", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/445e9e53a1e3bef38eecec7d79d1d99f2eaa9642).

Answer (score 2):

Returns will break your loop. Try this:

```
$coins = array("BTC", "ETH", "DOGE", "WAVES");

$found = false;
foreach ($coins as $coin) {
    $string = 'BTC';
    if (strpos($string, $coin) !== FALSE) {
        echo "BTC print";
        $found = true;
    }
    $string1 = 'ETH';
    if (strpos($string1, $coin) !== FALSE) {
        echo "ETH print";
        $found = true;
    }
    $string2 = 'DOGE';
    if (strpos($string2, $coin) !== FALSE) {
        echo "DOGE print";
        $found = true;
    }
    $string3 = 'WAVES';
    if (strpos($string3, $coin) !== FALSE) {
        echo "WAVES print";
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo "Not found!";
}
```

If you are in a function, then you could add:

```
return $found;
```